# Pandas create new column base on groupby and apply lambda if statement

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby, apply

I have the issue with `groupby` and `apply`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'B': np.r_[1:8]})
```

I want to create a column `C` for each group take value 1 if `B > z_score=2` and 0 otherwise. The code:

```
from scipy import stats
df['C'] = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: 1 if np.abs(stats.zscore(x['B'], nan_policy='omit')) > 2 else 0, axis=1)
```

However, I am unsuccessful with code and cannot figure out the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)with lambda, function, then compare and for convert `True/False` to `1/0` convert to integers:

```
from scipy import stats

s = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: np.abs(stats.zscore(x, nan_policy='omit')))
df['C'] = (s > 2).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['C'] = np.where(s > 2, 1, 0)
```

Error in your solution is per groups:

```
from scipy import stats

df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: 1 if np.abs(stats.zscore(x, nan_policy='omit')) > 2 else 0)
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

If check gotcha in [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas):

> pandas follows the NumPy convention of raising an error when you try to convert something to a bool. This happens in an if-statement or when using the boolean operations: and, or, and not.

So if use one of solutions instead `if-else`:

```
from scipy import stats

df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: (np.abs(stats.zscore(x, nan_policy='omit')) > 2).astype(int))

print (df)
A
a       [0, 0, 0]
b    [0, 0, 0, 0]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

but then need convert to column, for avoid this problems is used `groupby.transform`.

Comment: It's a good solution. But do you know where is it wrong with my code? I cannot figure it out. Many thanks

Comment: @PTQuoc - added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` + `apply` a function that finds the z-scores of each item in each group; explode the resulting list; use `gt` to create a boolean series and convert it to dtype int

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: stats.zscore(x, nan_policy='omit')).explode(ignore_index=True).abs().gt(2).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  a  1  0
1  a  2  0
2  a  3  0
3  b  4  0
4  b  5  0
5  b  6  0
6  b  7  0
```